# How to call method on return key and also on ipad down arrow key

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

[image]I have method for textfield animation which is running on after resignfirsrresponder i want that method also be called when user presses down arrow of the ipad which hides keyboard any idea how to do this. thanks.

I have added screenshots the button beside ABC text button i when we press that button normally keyboards hides i want to call animation on that button click.

Comment: use textfiled resignFirstResponder in
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ipad down arrow key You can use notification

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];

-(void)keyboardWillHide
{
//call when key board hides
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the textfield animation method in any one of the following `UITextFieldDelegate` methods

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have added screen shot please check what i want

Answer (score 0):

just write your code inside

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


}
```

And don't forget to bind textfield delegate and write `<UITextfieldDelegate>` in .h file

Answer (score 0):

if you want use done button on key board take one view with done button and write this method

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    [textField setInputAccessoryView:self.doneView];
}
```

and then give following action to that done button

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I have added screen shots check that